# how to remove default.aspx as default page from my application

Tags: asp.net

I have changed Home.aspx to the default page but still when I run the app it is still going to default.aspx page. When I delete the default.aspx page and then I run it gives an exception that page not find (not 404 page not found). In some other page when I click on Grid row it should fire a grid row command but it calls default.aspx page first and then it fires the row command event. There is a connection between row command and default.aspx page, no response.redirect event from javascript but I don't know why it is calling DEFAULT.ASPX page.

**Problem occurs only in IE**

I have already set Home.aspx as default page but still it is searching for Default.aspx page at startup  (Visual Studio).

Comment: Kind of hard to read what you're trying to communicate, but what about you change the default file in IIS?

Comment: Are you sure the absolute path with `default.aspx` in it is not recalled from history when you say it's only in IE?

Comment: When you say "Run App" do you mean run it up in visual studio? You can set the default page for VS separately from the default page for the app by right clicking in solution explorer and setting "Set as start page".

Comment: @Andrew yes running from VS, I have already set Home.aspx as default page but still it is searching for Default.aspx page at startup.

Comment: Could you search for "default.aspx" in your solution just in case there is some redirection forgotten.

Comment: @Frant I have searched in whole application but not found.

Answer (score 1):

If it is only problem in IE and works fine on other browsers, then consider clearing the cache of IE. Then do a hard refresh(CTRL+F5) of your web page.

Please recheck that you have mentioned the default document in web.config file.

If you are in hosting environment,then please select the default file from IIS setting for start pages from the control panel.

Comment: Ctrl+F5 done but still not working, I have already set Home.aspx as default page but still it is searching for Default.aspx page at startup

Comment: Right CLick on the solution project name -> Properties -> Start Page.


Set the name of the start page here.

Answer (score 0):

*If you have already tried right clicking the page and selecting Set as Startup Page , Did you checked in Visual studio site property pages, in start options list item there is "Start URL" and specific page properties. try changing these values ?

- Did you checked if you are using built in asp.net URL routing or any other URL routing modules,handlers etc?

PS: if you are using web application project rather than web site project this setting is [yourapp]>properties>web>StartAction>StartURL

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any javascript or jquery, please check that  any default redirection (like ~/ or /) is there.